# Deny from in apache not being used in include file

Tags: apache

I've added an include in a virtual host for a config which includes a file that contains deny from's.

The include appears to be added and parsed as entering nonsense in the include file will result in the Apache finding errors when testing the config. However, when adding deny froms in the include file they do not seem to be blocked, yet adding a deny from in an htaccess file in the directory works perfectly.

Not sure what could be causing this - any help is greatly appriciated

Comment: Does it work if you place the actual contents of the included file directly in the location where you include them?

Comment: Hi Lanzz, Just tried that now, and unfortunately when placing the deny from in the actual vhost, there is no effect:

Comment: Apparently you have a problem with your `Deny` rules, not with the file beind included.

Comment: Looks like I don't have mod_access, so I'll add that. However, wouldn't this impact the htaccess file as well? Because deny from's in htaccess files are obeyed

Comment: If you did not have the module that parses the `Deny` directives, your Apache would have refused to start due to unparsable configuration. I still suspect the error is in your specific `Deny` rules.

Comment: I've placed my virtual host config with the deny from here: https://gist.github.com/2843298 but when apache tests the config, no errors occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `Order Deny,Allow`, the `Allow from all` directive takes precedence and allows all requests. You need to change it to `Order Allow,Deny`.